# Can't find algorithm implementation in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier, viola-jones

I cannot find the implementation of the Voila-Jones-algorithm that is useing Haar features in OpenCV.

I have an [example class](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) from that I want to follow the method calls via F12 in VisualStudio. What I want is to jump througt the .cpp files to see the implementations. But what I get is only the declaration in the .hpp files. For example, the calls I want to follow are detectMultiScale(...) and CascsadeClassifier.

With the standard download of OpenCV 3.0 and 3.1, I could run the example class, but, as mentioned, couldn't F12 throug the code. 
I tried to build openCV from the sources on github by [this tutorial](https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/) but I get Linker Errors like

> main.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""void __cdecl cv::imshow(class cv::String const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABVString@1@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z)"
>   and 
>   1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "opencv_aruco310d.obj" kann nicht geöffnet werden.

when I want to run the code.

Building ends without failures, but when I want to add  the additional dependencies to the VS project, there are only .lib files for the debugger, none for the release.

Can anybody help?

Comment: compile opencv in release mode, too...

Comment: haar cascade classifier is somewhere in the code, just search with tools like notepad++ within the whole folder's files. It shares functions with HoG and LBP but haar uses "old cascade" branch afair.